# "Cannot rollback - no transaction is active (code 1)" when using Android Room library on API 23 device

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I am getting this error when I run my app on an API 23 device using the Room library. It happens on first launch, but I cannot get past my introduction in the app because it happens every time.

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: cannot rollback - no transaction is active (code 1)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecute(SQLiteConnection.java)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute(SQLiteConnection.java:553)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransactionUnchecked(SQLiteSession.java:439)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:401)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:522)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:262)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
       at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:92)
       at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:53)
       at androidx.room.SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.java:90)
       at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:476)
       at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:281)
       at com.diamonddevelopment.cardapp.data.CardMasterDao_Impl.getAllTags(CardMasterDao_Impl.java:1381)
       at com.diamonddevelopment.cardapp.data.AppRepository.getAllTags(AppRepository.kt:158)
       at com.diamonddevelopment.cardapp.activities.MainActivity$Companion$loadTags$1.run(MainActivity.kt:316)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This doesn't occur on API 24 and above. Is it a bug? This is how I create my room database:

```
fun getAppDatabase(context: Context): CardMasterDatabase? {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, CardMasterDatabase::class.java, FILE_NAME).createFromAsset("databases/$FILE_NAME").build()
            }
            return INSTANCE
        }
```

And how I use it:

```
 private var cardMasterDao: CardMasterDao? = null

    init {
        cardMasterDao = when {
            CardMasterDatabase.INSTANCE != null -> {
                CardMasterDatabase.INSTANCE!!.cardMasterDao()
            }
            else -> {
                CardMasterDatabase.getAppDatabase(context)!!.cardMasterDao()
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit:

`getAllTags` in `AppRepository`:

```
suspend fun getAllTags(): List<Tag> {
    return cardMasterDao!!.getAllTags()
}
```

`getAllTags` in `CardMasterDao`:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Tag")
suspend fun getAllTags(): List<Tag>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code of `getAllTags`?

Comment: @LucasS. I have added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some users had the [same issue with API 22](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/114626323).

You can try suggestions form the link:

- Not using deferred foreign keys to relax constraints
- Make sure your disk is not full
- Use `JournalMode.TRUNCATE`
- Catch the exception

If you say it's gone with API 24, I guess this is a bug.

Since you're not using any explicit transaction, I would say your best chance is to catch the exception explicitly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does this mean that I would have to catch it with every query?

Comment: Potentially... Does it happen with every query? And when you catch the Exception, is your query still returning the expected result?

Comment: Actually, now that you say that, I don't understand how I would catch it in the first place if the exception happens in the build files, and it doesn't get to the point where it returns anything?

Comment: I have actually discovered that the issue comes from the disk being full like you mentioned since it stopped when I increased the size of the internal storage of the emulator. I guess I will have to check this when I launch my app.

Comment: I had the same issue becuse I don't have free space on my phone